# foreach loop does not loop all

Tags: c#, foreach

Here is my code:

```
private void button_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGV_request.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "ACCEPT")
                {
                    ((dynamic)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()]).accept();
                    dataGV_connected.Rows.Add(false, row.Cells[0].Value);
                    dataGV_request.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((dynamic)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()]).deny();
                    dataGV_request.Rows.Remove(row);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

it's only do first row, not all.

Can anyone let me know why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're changing the collection while looping over it, probably not the best idea.

Comment: This is most likely throwing an exception that you are swallowing because you can't modify a collection during a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution, never modify the collection in a foreach loop.  Change it to for.

```
private void button_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGV_request.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGV_request.Rows[i];
        if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "ACCEPT")
            {
                ((dynamic)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()]).accept();
                dataGV_connected.Rows.Add(false, row.Cells[0].Value);
                dataGV_request.Rows.Remove(row);
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                ((dynamic)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()]).deny();
                dataGV_request.Rows.Remove(row);
                i--;
            }
        }

    }
}
```